# Automatic scroll to top on „next page"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Example URL](http://testserver.myopinion-online.de/questionnaire/survey/accesscode/czv)

Here's my issue: When I resize the browser (approx. 320 px width), scroll down and click on the icon (green arrow) „next“ the scroll bar stays at the bottom of the page. What I want to achieve is something like

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
});
```

so the next page will autoscroll to top, but I've tried with no success. Is there any solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, I tested it on your site it's working there:

```
$('button[id^="question"]').click(function(){
  $('#header-wrapper').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
});
```

Scroll bar is on #header-wrapper element and not body. scrolling body wont do anything since it's already at 0 scroll height.

Comment: Select it as right answer so others can find it too

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the animation to your (I guess) ajax success function.

```
success:function(e){
    // load the new contents
    setTimeout(function(){
           $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    },50);
 }
```

If it's not ajax you are using, add it to the button click event handler.